# Stripe Swift Use of unresolved identifier STPPaymentConfiguration

Tags: xcode, swift, платежи

Всем привет! 
Я хочу в своем проекте использовать Stripe и после того как я установил Stripe framework 12 через cocoapods, я добавил код указанный на фото, так как говорят на их официальном сайте. 
Но почему то выскакивает что 'STPPaymentConfiguration' не существует.

Может кто нибудь пожалуйста помочь решить эту проблему ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Название проекта (target) не должно быть Stripe